Function returns UNDEFINED while scipt does returns values
I was able to run this script and get the values out of the response. Happy as I was, I wrapped the script in a function and then it returned UNDEFINED. I am pulling all my hairs because the script without the function returns values in the consolelog but the function does not. ANy help is very appreciated.
\ SCRIPT
var tokenaddress = '2G3Gm6yZ2ZYu5B5rT7Fp8M1PyxdFAuhQ9VUhGTyBQYUJ'
var site = 'https://gmgn.ai/defi/quotation/v1/tokens/sol/';

var tokenurl = site + tokenaddress;
var graphurl = 'https://gmgn.ai/sol/token/' + tokenaddress;

var axios = require('axios');
axios.get(tokenurl)
    .then(function (response) {
    
    token = (response.data).data.token;
    var tokenName = token.name;
    var tokenLiquidity = token.liquidity;
    
    
    console.log('TokenName: ', tokenName,  'tokenLiquidity: ', tokenLiquidity);
});



OUTPUT: TokenName:  Kim Kardashian tokenLiquidity:  0.21558013114
When I wrap this script in a function it returns UNDEFINED. why I do not understand since I get values in de consolelog
\ FUNCTION
function FnGetToken(tokenaddress) {
var site = 'https://gmgn.ai/defi/quotation/v1/tokens/sol/';

var tokenurl = site + tokenaddress;
var graphurl = 'https://gmgn.ai/sol/token/' + tokenaddress;

var axios = require('axios');
axios.get(tokenurl)
    .then(function (response) {
    
    var token = (response.data).data.token
    var tokenName = token.name
    var tokenLiquidity = token.liquidity; 
    
    return  tokenName, tokenLiquidity
    
}
    
)
    
}
console.log(FnGetToken('2G3Gm6yZ2ZYu5B5rT7Fp8M1PyxdFAuhQ9VUhGTyBQYUJ'));

OUTPUT: undefined
read about undefined but couldnt make the function to work

In order to provide a more focused answer for your question, please share which environment you're running. Specially which Operating System you're using to run such scripts.
